# Can I safely attach a magnet to the back of a Wii U gamepad?

Tags: controllers, wii-u

I backed a Kickstarter [project](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1893116150/bungajungle-worlds-most-versatile-stands) for a flexible, magnetic iPad stand. I'm wondering if I could use it for my Wii U Gamepad as well.

A magnet is attached to the back of the device (semipermanently) to secure it on the stand. The magnets are supposed to be "shielded", and safe for use on a laptop with an HDD. They will trip the sleep sensor on a MacBook Pro however, so I'm a little concerned if it will affect the gamepad.

Would attaching a magnet to the back of the Wii U Gamepad cause damage? Will the orientation sensors still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tanner,

With the Bungajungle stands the magnetic field does not pass the disks that are attached to the back of your device.  That is why it can be used with HD laptops.

I'll be putting up more info on the website and also if others are interested.  www.bungajungle.com or the kickstarter page:
http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1893116150/bungajungle-worlds-most-versatile-stands

Answer (score 3):

No, it should not. Wii U gamepads do not contain traditional hard drives, as they do not need that kind of storage. As a result, magnets should do no damage to your hardware.